# How are the out variables of vertex shader interpolated?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, vulkan

To my understanding, input attributes of vertex computed in vertex will be interpolated according to barycentric coordinate of current pixel. And being able to interpolate `attributes`  or to compute barycentric coordinate of current pixel is because the vertex stream is transited to triangle stream after vertex shader. The barycentric coordinate of current pixel can be derived by the screen positions of triangle vertices provided by `gl_Position` and the pixel position.

But I'm confused how to interpolate `in` variables in fragment shader. Here is an exampler of shader:

- vertex shader

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform WorldMVP {
    mat4 worldMvp;
};
layout(binding = 0) uniform LightMVP{
    mat4 lightMvp;
};
layout(location = 0) in vec3 aVertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aVertexNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTextureCoord;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 vPositionFromLight;
layout(location = 1) out vec2 vTextureCoord;
layout(location = 2) out vec3 vNormal;
void mian()
{
    gl_Position = worldMvp * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vPositionFromLight = lightMvp * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    vNormal = aVertexNormal;
}
```

- fragment shader

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPositionFromLight;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vTextureCoord;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vNormal;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

If the barycentric coordinate used in interpolating `vPositionFromLight` is same as the one used in interpolating attributes like `vTextureCoord` and `vNormal`, it seems abnormal. Because `vPositionFromLight` and `gl_Position` are transformed into different clip spaces by different MVP.

How does the `vPositionFromLight` is interpolated? What is the barycentric coordinate used in interpolating  `vPositionFromLight`.

Comment: @KaiBurjack Thanks for your explanation. Is the barycentric coordinate of clip space transformed by light MVP same as the one of clip space transformed by world MVP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because vPositionFromLight and gl_Position are transformed into different clip spaces by different MVP.

As far as OpenGL is concerned, they're just *numbers*. Is `vPositionFromLight` in a "clip space"? OpenGL doesn't care; they are a `vec4`, and that `vec4` will get the same interpolation math as any other vertex shader output.

The space of the post-interpolation value is the same space as the pre-interpolation result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand your answer.